# How to create a python program where some libraries are automatically installed

Tags: python, libraries

I have created a program that uses some external libraries such as matplotlib, NumPy, pandas... I want to share my program with other users. The problem is that those users need to install those libraries and I want to avoid that. I have read that an executable file can be created, however, I want the other users could also be able to edit the program. How could I do this?

Comment: The best practice is to create a `requirements.txt` file that contains all the libraries required and install them before running your program using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you share the program as an executable file then it is true that the user won't have to install the libraries. But once the code is converted it can not be edited, each time you edit the code you will need to convert it every time to update the version. If you want to share editable code then the best option is to share a requirements.txt file along with the program.

You can generate requirements.txt which lists all your current dependencies. Use pipreqs module to list only the libraries used in your program.
install pipreqs (without $)

```
$ pip install pipreqs
```

Then go to your program directory and in the terminal/PowerShell/command prompt type (without $)

```
$ pipreq .
```

it will generate requirements.txt in the program directory zip the entire folder and share it. User need to install from this requirements.txt file, they can install from the file using the following command (without $)

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I have another question regarding this topic. How do you ensure that the person that is going to use the program has pip already installed and the system variables path is well defined?

Comment: There's a way to do this, this will change whether the user is using Linux or windows.
For windows - you will have to make a batch script to check whether pip is installed
For Linux - you will have to make a shell script to check whether pip is installed

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add a **requirements.txt**. This is a file where one specifies dependencies for a certain project. For example your program can have dependency on a certain *NumPy* version and by adding it to the requirements.txt file, when another user needs to install the dependencies for that project, he can easily automate it.

If you are using a virtual environment, you could simply get the environment.txt doing a `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Otherwise you might need to add the used libraries to this file by yourself.

To let other people install the dependencies on their environment, they will need to execute the following *pip* command instead of installing every single module:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using the requirements file is the way to go and a common standard. You can create the requirements file using the following pip command:

```sh
$ cd <root directory>
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```